# How to use differentiation to find the maximum area of a triangle inscribed in a square

Tags: calculus

[image]

I wanted to know that how can I find the maximum area of the triangle inscribed in a square, it is given that $AE:AF = 1:2 $,  $ABCD$ is a square, each side of length $a$.

Thanks

Comment: Put $AE=x$. Now find the areas of the three outer triangles, and hence (by subtraction) the area of $CEF$ in terms of $x$. Differentiate to find the critical point.

Comment: The length of each side is _a_ If I put _AE=x_ , there will be more than one unknown (how can I finish it?) I am sorry that I am really poor at this topic :(

Comment: No, $a$ is a constant, so there is only one variable. You have $DE=a-x,AF=2x,BF=a-2x,BC=CD=a$. So for example area $AEF=x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

We are free to assume $a=1$ and 
$$AE = x,\quad AF = 2x,\quad BF=1-2x,\quad DE=1-x. $$
Then we have to find the maximum value of 
$$ 2[CEF] = 2-x(2x)-(1-x)-(1-2x) = 3x-2x^2$$
with $x\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$. But the last function is increasing over such interval ($f'>0$), hence the maximum value of $[CEF]$ is attained when $B\equiv F$.